# JavaScript Finite State Machine

Tags: javascript, forms, state-machine, fsm

**Problem Statement**:

I have a form that I need states applying to it as there are multiple possible scenarios but instead of a very bespoke and not very clean JavaScript class with if this is clicked and that is clicked but not this and that blah blah... I want to apply a state and a transition to cover the scenarios.

I want to use the [jakesgordon/javascript-state-machine](https://github.com/jakesgordon/javascript-state-machine) for modeling the states and their transitions. I was thinking along the lines of...

```
{
    initial: 'none',
    events: [
        { name: 'completing',   from: ['none', 'completing', 'complete', 'blocked'],    to: 'completing'    },
        { name: 'completed',    from: ['blocked', 'completing'],                        to: 'completed'     },
        { name: 'continue',     from: ['blocked', 'completed'],                         to: 'continue'      },
        { name: 'blocked',      from: ['none', 'completing', 'complete'],               to: 'blocked'       }
    ]
}
```

I would love some input on what the best states and transitions (and possibly when to transition them at each scenario) [callbacks](https://github.com/jakesgordon/javascript-state-machine#user-content-callbacks).

*The Form*

[The form UX pin can be found here.](https://jsfiddle.net/linxlad/gdeyLL4x/) (Too long for a screenshot).

***The Rules and their scenarios***

- ***Accessing the continue button***

State `complete` follows these rules:
The navigation "continue" button to Page 2 should be greyed out and unavailable until either of the following 2 scenarios have been met

**Scenario 1**

1).I am completing this screening tool... - User selects - Myself or Myself with the support of someone else

AND

2). Do you have any concerns about how others treat you? - User selects - No

AND

3). Do you find it difficult to communicate with others? - User selects - No

AND

4). Do you find it difficult to understand or to retain information? - User selects - No

AND

5). Do you find it difficult to make decisions or understand their impact? - User selects - No

**Scenario 2**

1).I am completing this screening tool... - User selects - On behalf of someone else

AND

2). All questions are completed

- ***Do You Have Any Concerns About How Others Treat You?***

State `blocked` follows these rules: There is conditional behavior on Page 1 which depends on which option is selected on the Do you have any concerns about how others treat you?

***Scenario 1***

I am completing this screening tool... - User selects - Myself

AND

Do you have any concerns about how others treat you? - User selects - Yes

1). The info alert for this section is displayed
2). The section Communication & understanding is greyed out and unavailable to the user

Do you have any concerns about how others treat you? - User selects - No

1). The info alert for this section is not displayed

2). The section Communication & understanding is ungreyed out and available to the user

***Scenario 2***

I am completing this screening tool... - User selects - Myself with the support of someone else or On behalf of someone else

AND

Do you have any concerns about how others treat you? - User selects - Yes

1). The info alert for this section is displayed
2). The section Communication & understanding is ungreyed out and available to the user

User selects - No

1). The info alert for this section is not displayed
2). The section Communication & understanding is ungreyed out and available to the user

When a user is completing the form then they are in `completing` state. Can anyone suggest the setup and when to change please.

Comment: Create class State, extend for different States. Create class StateMachine that starts operating on a starting state. Each state has methods that return the next logical state in case of an action. Use singletons for all classes using a DIC. Does this make sense? I could help flesh it out for you as an answer if my thought process seems relevant to you.

Edit: My team has built something *very* similar to manage complex animated custom-views on Android :)

Comment: What is your question now? "*I would like to get some input*" is a discussion, which is not suitable for StackOverflow.

Comment: @Angad: "singleton" and "class" don't go well together in JS

Comment: @Bergi Personally have switched out to writing TypeScript + Inversify, but agreed. While classes are still something you can engineer manually in POJS, I wouldn't dream of doing this without something like *bottle.js* since 'manual' singletons would become a testing nightmare

Comment: @Kal consider using https://github.com/jml6m/fas-js for modeling the FSA, it's a newer and more powerful library